# Can't resolve typescript class from typings file of imported module but works with absolute path

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript-typings

have two node projects as X,Y.  X has a typescript class calculator.ts and its exported in index.ts and X's package json has property of typings as below.

```
"typings": "dist/src/index.d.ts"
```

node project Y imports calculator as below

```js
import {Calculator} from 'X';
```

but it throws error

> internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
>       throw err;
>       ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module 'X'
>       at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)

it works when its imported from absolute path.

```js
import {Calculator} from 'X/dist/src/calculator';
```

Comment: Where is the `.js` file for `index.ts` located?  `dist/src/index.js`?  If so, the `main` field of X's `package.json` needs to specify that path in order for `import ... from 'X'` to find the module at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

`main` field of X's package.json should point to the `dist/src/index.js` to resolve exported classes at run time.

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main